# Embedding an image in email's body using $this->templating->render()

Tags: image, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using the next code inside a method to send one kind of email:

```
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setSubject($this->translator->trans("Invitación a la comunidad %community%", array(
            '%community%' => $community->getNiceName()
        )))
        ->setFrom('manolez@gmail.com', 'contact') // TODO DRY
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setReplyTo($inviter->getEmail(), $inviter->getFullName())
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setBody($this->templating->render(
            'ProInvitationsBundle:Invitations:inviteEmail.html.twig',
            array('community' => $community, 'inviter' => $inviter)));
```

I want to embed an image to the body, so I could do:

```
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setSubject($this->translator->trans("Invitación a la comunidad %community%", array(
            '%community%' => $community->getNiceName()
        )))
        ->setFrom('manolez@gmail.com', 'contact') // TODO DRY
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setReplyTo($inviter->getEmail(), $inviter->getFullName())
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setBody('<html><head></head><body>Here is an image <img src="' .
             $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('http://site.tld/logo.png')) .
         '" alt="Image" />' .
         '  Rest of message' .
         ' </body></html>');
```

but in this way, the `$message` is not defined yet, and also I can't render my template. Any idea of how to achieve to embed an image to my defined template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
$imgUrl = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('http://site.tld/logo.png'));
$message->setSubject($this->translator->trans("Invitación a la comunidad %community%", array(
        '%community%' => $community->getNiceName()
    )))
    ->setFrom('manolez@gmail.com', 'redConvive') // TODO DRY
    ->setTo($email)
    ->setReplyTo($inviter->getEmail(), $inviter->getFullName())
    ->setBody($this->templating->render(
        'ProInvitationsBundle:Invitations:inviteEmail.html.twig',
        array('community' => $community, 'inviter' => $inviter, 'url'=>$imgUrl)
    ), 'text/html');
```

for more detailed info on how to use SwiftMailer, it's always good to [Read the Documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-inline-media-files)

UPDATE

To include the image in a twig template, you use it like any other twig variable:

```
<img src="{{ url }}">
```

Comment: But a want to call a template for the `body`.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  the `$message-embed()` function returns what you need, so just put it in a var and pass it into the template.

Comment: Can you please add the code of the Twig file to show how `url` is used? DO you use a `<img src="">` tag?

Comment: you use it like any other twig variable. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to Sehael's answer.

This is how you generate the full URL. You can get the base URL using the request service:

```php
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$baseurl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath();

$url = $baseurl . '/img/logo.png';
```

- It will result in http://yoursite.com/img/logo.png
- logo.png is a file in your /web/img/ directory.